# Clear Input filed after Form submit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clear input field after submitting with `textcontent = ''` but it won't work.

```
const inputField = document.querySelector('.input');
document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (document.querySelector(`.position-${i}`).classList.contains('hidden')) {
            document.querySelector(`.position-${i}`).classList.remove('hidden')
            document.querySelector(`.text-${i}`).textContent = inputField.value
            document.querySelector('.input').textContent = ''
            if (!document.querySelector(`.position-${i}`).classList.contains('hidden')) break
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Makes no sense to `.remove` a className `"hidden"`, and then go check of it's removed.

Comment: Also, I'm afraid you're doing something terribly wrong. Seems like you're treating Classes as *unique selectors*. Usually, when using classes, you want to loop them all. Otherwise it's clear sign you might want to use IDs - or... no selectors at all. (Sometimes you can go for attribute selectors like `[name="something"]` etc...) Without seeing the HTML and the real problem surrounding your question - hard to tell.

Comment: Please [edit] with a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: Use `.value` instead of `.textContent`, `document.querySelector('.input').value = ''`. I hope `.input` is input tag

Answer (score 3):

To reset a form use [HTMLFormElement.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

```js
const elForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");

elForm.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault(); // Don't follow default form action

  elForm.reset(); // Reset form elements to default values

  // Remove class "hidden" from elements that have such class
  elForm.querySelectorAll(".hidden").forEach((elHidden) => {
    elHidden.classList.remove("hidden");
  });

});
```

Besides that,

the [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) has no `.textContent` setter.
Use eventually `.value` instead (* read below about the implications of doing so)

```js
// WARNING! Don't use this example to "reset" an input value!
document.querySelector('input').value = '';
```

***but***

- such will only operate on the **first** `<input>` that's found in your app.
- it will **not reset** the input value, rather it will override it to an empty string.

Instead, use `.defaultValue`:

To account for all your inputs of a specific form use:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input, #myForm textarea").forEach(elInp => {
  elInp.value = elInp.defaultValue;
});
```

You can also use [HTMLFormElement.elements](https:////developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) to iterate over a live HTMLFormControlsCollection:

```js
const elForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");

// Let's modify the values on the fly
elForm.querySelector('[name="title"]').value = "222";
elForm.querySelector('[name="content"]').value = "Ipsum";

// Let's reset to their default values:
[...elForm.elements].forEach((el) => {
  el.value = el.defaultValue;
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="myForm">
  <input name="title" type="text" value="123"><br>
  <textarea name="content">Lorem</textarea>
</form>
```

Again, that's useful to **reset only specific** elements. Otherwise use the Form's `.reset()` method.

Comment: Why *"WARNING! Don't use this example to "reset" an input value!
"*?

Comment: @Normal read further.